# Ошибка в формуле Google Sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet

есть формула

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1;ДВССЫЛ("^\d{2}-\d{6}"))
```

Которая проверяет значение в ячейке по маске 99-999999 только первое условие где 2 цифры, на второе не реагирует.
Если добавить сделать маску "^\d{2}-^\d{6}" выдаёт ложь при верном значение.
Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

=REGEXMATCH(A1, "^\d{2}-\d{6}$")

В этой формуле мы использовали маску ^\d{2}-\d{6}$, которая проверяет значение ячейки на соответствие следующим условиям:

```
начало строки: ^
две цифры: \d{2}
дефис: -
шесть цифр: \d{6}
конец строки: $
```

Таким образом, эта формула будет возвращать ИСТИНА только в том случае, если значение в ячейке соответствует обоим условиям.